# OpenCV Build Error: "Cannot open options file specified with @"

Tags: 12.04, make, opencv, cmake

I am having trouble installing OpenCV on my machine. I run Ubuntu 12.04.

I have followed this guide: http://www.raben.com/book/export/html/3 in order to install OpenCV 2.4.3 on my linux machine. However, when I execute the

```
make
```

command, "making" stops at 14%, returns the following error

```
13%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 13%] Generating qrc_window_QT.cxx
[ 14%] Generating src/moc_window_QT.cxx
moc: Cannot open options file specified with @
Usage: moc [options] <header-file>
  -o<file>           write output to file rather than stdout
  -I<dir>            add dir to the include path for header files
  -E                 preprocess only; do not generate meta object code
  -D<macro>[=<def>]  define macro, with optional definition
  -U<macro>          undefine macro
  -i                 do not generate an #include statement
  -p<path>           path prefix for included file
  -f[<file>]         force #include, optional file name
  -nn                do not display notes
  -nw                do not display warnings
  @<file>            read additional options from file
  -v                 display version of moc
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/src/moc_window_QT.cxx] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and then terminates. I have also installed all the required dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

have you accentuated characters in your working directory name ? (see https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35480 )

Comment: Please don't answer with things that should be commentaries (this isn't an answer). I recommend you to make 10 reputation and then comment. Or you can answer direclty if you have a suitable answer

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. On Askubuntu, please only post as an answer if it is an answer. If you need additional information to come to an answer, you should use the option to comment.

Comment: While not phrased like an answer it most certainly is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an accented character in the path name to the source files you may get this error. Move the source directory to a directory so that there is no accented characters in the path name. Then restart the compilation.